# Python/Windows: Writing to virtual file that is actually memory stream

Tags: python, stream, powerpoint, win32com

I am trying to use the win32com.client module to store raw image data. To save a power point application as JPG using python in Windows, one can use the following:

```
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(r"your_path")
Presentation.Slides[0].Export(r"the_new_path-file.jpg", "JPG")
Application.Quit()
Presentation =  None
Application = None
```

So, is there a way to trick this code into thinking it is writing to a file (when really it is writing to a variable)?

Comment: If it accepts a file name, then no.

Comment: It does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.export There’s nothing I can do in the file system itself outside of python (like a TTY device)???

Comment: No.  Windows is not that smart.  Files are easy to handle; just let it export to file, and then read the file.